# Is it possible to bind a handler to a jQuery effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I would like to call function when slideUp or slideDown are performed on an element. Is this possible?

Something like:

```
$('#panel').on('slideUp', function() { open--; });
$('#panel').on('slideDown', function() { open++; });
```

Update: The problem is that there are a ton of slide calls (e.g.: $().slideUp()) all over the page, within ajax responses, hash link clicks, etc.. I was hoping to bind to the slide itself somehow rather than add code to each calling function.

Comment: Use the callbacks of the slide methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind to an event since there is no such.

But you can pass a handler that will be called after animation is finished

```
$('#panel').slideUp(function() { ... });
```

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: This would have worked. I ran into another obstacle that made this whole thing infeasible, but up until that, this was going well. :) Thanks. I wasn't aware of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, you can use custom events and your own little plugin, something like this:

```
$.fn.mySlideToggle = function() {
  this.slideToggle();
  this.trigger('mySlideToggle');
}

$('div').on('mySlideToggle', function(){ console.log('hey') });
$('button').on('click', function(){ $('div').mySlideToggle(); });
```

Here's a little demo (check console): http://jsbin.com/asejif/2/edit

In your case it is redundant though, since you can use the callback that the slide events provide, but it might be useful for other things...